# Finite intersection of open sets

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove the following proposition:

> Let $\tau$ be a topology. A finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ is also in $\tau$.

My attempt:

> The proof is by induction on the number of elements in the intersection.
>
> Base case: an element of $\tau$ is in $\tau$ by definition.
>
> Suppose that the statement holds for intersections of $k\lt n$ elements. Let $S$ be an intersection of $n$ elements. The intersection of the first $n-1$ elements is in $\tau$ (by the induction hypothesis). Now we have an intersection of two elements of $\tau$ which is an element of $\tau$ (again by the induction hypothesis).

Is my proof correct?

Comment: yes, this proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine. However, I'm wondering why this is a theorem, and not just a consequence of the definition of a topology.

Comment: @Stahl It's an exercise in a book. Is it wrong to call it a theorem? I taught a theorem is just a statement for which there is a proof.

Comment: @saadtaame Yes, theorem, proposition, lemma, corollary  all mean the same by the end of the day. But this result is too humble to go under the label "theorem".

Comment: I'm not objecting to you calling it a theorem, (although I agree with @HagenvonEitzen in that it's a bit "small" to be a full blown theorem) I'm wondering why the result isn't immediate from the definition of a topology. The definition I'm familiar with is:
Let $X$ be a set and let $\tau\subset\mathscr{P}(X)$. Then $\tau$ is called a topology on $X$ if:
1. $\emptyset,X\in\tau$,
2. Any arbitrary union of elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$, and 
3. Any intersection of finitely many elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$

Comment: @Ittay: Not quite: see Hagen’s answer. The induction has to start with $2$ as the base case.

Comment: @Hagen: It is not incorrect to call it a theorem; a little unusual, perhaps, but not actually incorrect.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how true! everything was perfect up to the unnecessary bracketed remark. Good spotting!

Comment: @Stahl: The definition that merely requires the intersection of two open sets to be open is at least as common, in my experience.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, formally that is not incorrect. But I would not have dared to call it anything more egregious than "remark" :)

Comment: @saadtaame: consider empty intersection too, if it is a finite intersection,

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ah, fair enough. I simply think of it as $\tau$ closed under finite intersections, as they're equivalent, and there's generally no harm in stating it in such a way.

Comment: @CutieKrait The empty intersection yields $\emptyset$ which is in $\tau$ by definition. No?

Comment: @Hagen: Well yes. But maybe: First topology course, first encounter: theorem/proposition. Senior project: remark. Dissertation: not worth mentioning.

Comment: @CutieKrait: Actually, $\bigcap\varnothing$ is vacuously the whole space, is open.

Comment: @saadtaame: No. it yeilds $X$ = whole space.

Comment: @CutieKrait Counter-intuitive..

Comment: @saadtaame: empty intersection (that is the intersection of zero number of sets) depends on the space. it is defined to be the whole space. and this definition is compatible with logical deductions.

Comment: Guys, can I add more proof attempts to this thread or do I have to create separate threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last step is not correct. The intersection of two open sets is open *by definition of topology* and not by induction hypothesis.

Consider this:

**Theorem:** If $A$ is a finite set, all of its elements are equal.

*Proof:* If $|A|=1$, the claim is trivially true.
Suppose the statement holds for finite sets of $k<n$ elements. 
Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements. Then the first $n-1$ elements are equal by induction hypothesis. 
Also the last two elements are equal by induction hypothesis.
Therefore all $n$ elements are equal as was to be shown $_\square?$

Comment: What's wrong with your proof? I can't find the flaw!

Comment: @saadtaame: The argument used in the induction step doesn’t actually work when $n=1$.

Comment: @Brian: With Hagen's notations do you mean when $n=2$? Which would be the same as $n=1$ if induction assumption would be for $k\leq n$ instead of $k<n$. Or did I misinterpret something?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I did.